# Error "echo:too long extrusion prevented" when printing a model I made in Blender

Tags: extruder

I am new to 3D printing but decided to follow the build-your-own-printer route. It’s a simple design running on Marlin with a RAMPS 1.4 board.

So far I have printed the 2 mm calibration cube and two other small objects from Thingiverse and they all turn out fine. However, for over three weeks, I have been unsuccessfully trying to print a model I made in Blender. I keep getting an `echo: too long extrusion prevented` error on Pronterface and then the printer briefly pauses before resuming and afterward, the filament snaps out of the extruder or jams the nozzle leading to a failed print.

I have searched the internet for solutions and these are what I have done so far:

- I have reduced the voltage on the trim pot on the stepper driver (A4988) the heat sinks do seem to get pretty hot to the touch.
- I have reduced the print speed to 60%
- I have added a bed offset on the firmware to properly center the prints. (This seems to create other issues so I reversed it back to the way it was before)

Could someone please help me out here to understand what I am doing wrong? The part I am trying to print is actually meant to replace the wooden plate I used to carry one of the stepper motors.

I have attached a picture of my screen on Pronterface showing the model and the error message.

[image: Picture of my screen on Pronterface]

Answer (score 1):

This error is nothing wrong with your printer, its electronics, print speed, or anything like that. It's erroneous gcode, produced by a buggy slicer, that emitted a command to extrude an inordinately large amount of filament at a time, in a way that could not possibly work. Your printer's firmware is protecting it from actually trying to do that.

To try to track down the problem, look at the gcode at the point where the error occurs. If you can't make sense of it, post the gcode file (or even better, just a block quote of the relevant part inline in your question) and someone should be able to explain what's going on and why it occurred.

Just upgrading your slicer might fix it, though.

Comment: Thank you for the help. Following your suggestion i downloaded prusa slicer and used it.  Unfortunately i still had the same "echo: too long extrusion prevented" followed by brief pause in filament extrusion and a subsequent snapping of the filament from the extruder. I am aware that stepper drivers can briefly pause motion of the stepper motors to cool off but in this case the pause only start to happen after pronterface shows "too long extrusion prevented " I dont know if these problems are related or not. I wanted to attach the gcode file but i am unable to figure out where to do that here

Comment: So I figured out why I am having the too long extrusion problem but I am yet to find a solution. It seems despite my best efforts the extruder pushes out filament  that turns into a kind of road-block along the extruder path so blocking its movement and triggering the “echo too long extrusion prevented” message. These road blocks  so to say occur at random places making it difficult to pinpoint the cause. I have checked the Z axis steps/mm it is fine. I am really at a loss as to what else I can do or check. Hoping someone will be able to help out

Comment: @belloalmu: Again, this error is nothing mechanical/physical with your printer. It would happen even if you ran the gcode on your controller board with all the motors unplugged. If it's not happening at exactly the same point in each print, but seemingly randomly, it's probably a communication error between Pronterface and your printer (data corruption on the serial line), flipping a bit in some of the gcode commands in a way that makes it request an enormous amount of extrusion.